# How to build a for each with a customized Module

Tags: vb.net

I have built a customized module to get elements by classname, but I can not get it to work with for each function. Well I tried to get the loop on the code that calld my elements by classname which is a customized module.

Normally its easy to get the loop but with this Customized Module, I can not find the way to this to work. I am new yet on vb, and I can not find any example to do it right. This is my code I need to perform a loop

I need some something like this:

```
For Each cuele In ele
 
Next
```

But it gives me an error

> Expression is of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement', which is not a collection type

I have try in a different way, but I get a null exception

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form3
Dim WithEvents htmldoc As HtmlDocument


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'TextBox1.Text = ""
    
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    htmldoc = WebBrowser1.Document

    'WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("click")
    'WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements


        'ListBox1.Items.Add(webpageelement.GetAttribute("title").ToString)
        'ListBox1.Items.Add(webpageelement.GetAttribute("href").ToString)
        Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("time")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement
            'TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + CurElement.GetAttribute("Liga NOS") + Environment.NewLine
            'ListBox2.Items.Add(CurElement.GetAttribute("datetime") + Environment.NewLine)

        Next
        Dim PageElement2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement2
            'TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + CurElement.GetAttribute("Liga NOS") + Environment.NewLine
            'ListBox1.Items.Add(CurElement.GetAttribute("data-content") + Environment.NewLine)

        Next
        Dim PageElement3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement3
            'TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + CurElement.GetAttribute("Liga NOS") + Environment.NewLine
            'ListBox3.Items.Add(CurElement.GetAttribute("alt") + Environment.NewLine)

        Next

        
        

    Next
    For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next i

    For i As Integer = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox2.GetItemText(ListBox2.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
            ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Dim ele As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("league-data")(0)
    'TextBox1.Text = ele.InnerText
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ele.InnerText)
    Dim ArrayTag As New ArrayList
For Each item As HtmlElement In 
Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
ArrayTag.Add(item.InnerText)
Next
ListBox2.Items.Add(ArrayTag(64))
    
    
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: You need to explain your issue a little better. Place more code. Are you using windowsforms?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso i just edit to post more code

Comment: @RenatoAfonso yes i use windows forms

Comment: Like the error says. `ele` is a single htmlelement not a collection of them

Comment: @DavidWilson tank for replay well i am new on vb and well i can not find any example how to do it in the correct way, could you please have a kind to give an example. Tank you in advance

Comment: I would, but in my Visual Studio, `GetElementsByClassName` doesnt seem to exist. And I can't find a reference to it on microsft's site. What version of .net are you using?

Comment: @DavidWilson i use 2012 and this is a module i have build for i can sen maybe by google drive

Comment: @DavidWilson here it is the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FNZaMbfaajAJzhjV0DWpu0qH8LmW9Udm

Answer (score 0):

OK This might well work, but I can't test it. I've altered the extension a little, so that it creates a list rather than a HtmlElementCollection (It seems that these are read-only)

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function GetElementsByClassName(Source As HtmlElementCollection, ClassName As String) As List(Of HtmlElement)
    Dim output As New List(Of HtmlElement)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Source.Count - 1
        Try
            If Source(i).GetAttribute("className") = ClassName Then
                output.Add(Source(i))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
    Return output
End Function
```

And edited the form code so that it also deals with a list instead of the `HtmlElementCollection`

```
For Each cuele As HtmlElement In ele
    ListBox2.Items.Add(cuele.InnerText)
Next
```

Hopefully this should work.

I also suggest that you use a list instead of an ArrayList as Lists are faster and strongly typed ..

```
Dim ArrayTag As New List(Of String)
For Each item As HtmlElement In Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    ArrayTag.Add(item.InnerText)
Next
ListBox2.Items.Add(ArrayTag(64))
```